# passing id parameter to a controller's create action internally using viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my model I have a one to many relationship between Users and Topics class. Code for the two classes is

```
public class Topic
{
    public int TopicID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; } 
    [Display(Name="Topic Subject")]
    public string TopicSubject { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime TopicDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public int CatagoryID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("FullName")]

    public virtual Catagory Catagories { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Reply> Replies { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string UserPass { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return FirstName + ", " + LastName; }
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Reply> Replies { get; set; }

}
```

In my controller the action method I used an int id parameter to pass the id internally from the view

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    ViewBag.CatagoryID = id;
    ViewBag.UserID = id;
    return View();
}
```

But when I try to access Topics/Create in my browser an error like this appears and it's bugging me:

[image]

Comment: As the error suggests you are not passing an id from you link to that page. If you do not know how to do this i would suggest a 'getting started with mvc' tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Your Create method is the HttpGet version - meaning, why are you passing the id for an object that hasn't been created in order to "create" an object?  This should be empty for a create, and the HttpPost should pass back the model so it can only then be created.

Try looking at the create mvc example: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part6

Answer (score 0):

For the controller to work you need to pass the id in the query parameters. So you need to use the below url.

http://localhost:63952/Topics/Create?id=1

If you want the id to be optional you need to change your action method like below.

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{
    ViewBag.CatagoryID = id;
    ViewBag.UserID = id;
    return View();
}
```

The above will tell C# id param is optional and MVC will not expect it to be present on the query parameters

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score -1):

Try localhost:63952/Create/5
5 refers to the id that you passed in the function Create
you can try any number it will works